How to clip one point layer from two different polygon layers
I am trying to clip one point layer from two different polygon layers (highway buffer layer and census tract layer). I can't do this individually because I don't want to double count the point features. Ideally, the point layer would remain as 1 layer when this is completed. Any advice on how to proceed with this?

Look at the spatial join tool.

If you stop using "Clip" to describe the "Identity" and/or "Intersect" operations, you will have an easier time identifying the correct documentation.

Can you clarify if you want a point layer that represents points that are in both polygon layers (that is, in the Census tract layer and the highway buffer), or that are in either polygon layer (for example, could fall into the Census tract layer but not be in the highway buffer)?

@LeeHachadoorian I want a point layer that represents points in either polygon layer.

OK. Answer below about unioning the layers before doing the clip is one possible solution.

I would try unioning the highway buffer and the census tract layer, this way you will have a single polygon layer that has both data sets. Then you can use the clip tool to clip the point layer.https://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/latest/tool-reference/analysis/union.htm
